# glutReshapeFunc() doesn't make any change

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to keep same ratio of viewport on different window resolutions. For that I use `glutReshapeFunc()` with `reshape()` as its argument. `reshape()` is called, and calculations seem to be correct, but viewport ratio isn't preserved.

Also, `reshape()` settings applied on launch, but when I change size of the window, viewport seems to be dropped to its default values.

How to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
const int windowWidth = 1200;
const int windowHeight = 600;

const int viewRatio = windowWidth/windowHeight;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow("Scene");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    initialise();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void initialise(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(60.0, ((float)windowWidth)/((float)windowHeight), 1.0, 20.0);
}

void reshape(int width, int height) {
    (viewRatio > width/height) ? glViewport(0, 0, width, width/viewRatio) : glViewport(0, 0, height*viewRatio, height);
}

void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
        gluLookAt(
            0.0, 0.0, 10.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0
        );

        // TODO: Implement the scene
        glutSolidSphere(3.0, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const int viewRatio = windowWidth/windowHeight;
> [...]
> (viewRatio > width/height) ? glViewport(0, 0, width, width/viewRatio) : glViewport(0, 0, height*viewRatio, height);
> ```

Don't use integers and integer arithmetic when you clearly need fractional values.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't make much sense since `reshape()` function has to take width and height as integer values, and window aspect ratio is constant in my case — it equals 2. 
Anyway, it doesn't work even if I use `float` type.

Comment: Even when `width` and `height` are integers, the calculation `width/height`  which you want to do will yield a non-integer value. However, as you have written it, `width/height` will yield an integer, but not a useful one. If `viewRatio` is 2, then `2 > 1499/500` will evaluate to `false` since `2 > 2` is `false`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, thank you for explanation. But it solved another bug, not the one I initially asked about